# Writing a script to rename a job file in process

Tags: bash, perl

I have a print program that converts a print job into afp to be sent to a third party. The issue is they look for a filename that is completely different than what the print program creates.  I have a portion of the workflow where it can run an external program to create the filename after it has been processed and then save it to a directory on the file server, or SFTP it to another server. The problem I have is writing a script to make the actual change.

the filename created is (job#).print.afp

The file name format we are looking for is ACIF_OUTPUT_(date)*(timestamp)*(job#).afp

I started creating a bash to do it, but missing the part where it gets the file name to pull the job# from to insert it in the appropriate place.

```
#! /bin/bash
date_time=$(date +“%Y-%m-%d at %H,%M.%S)
Job=$(
file=”/usr/Transfers/ACIF_OUTPUT_${date_time}_{Job}.afp”
echo “Starting backup to $file…”
```

It can be perl or some other language as long as I can link to it to run.

This is for Ricoh Process Director if that matters. It will be triggered by StepTemplate RunExternalProgram.

Still working on figuring out the template.

If it is of any help, I found the perl that does the copy. If it can be done in here, that would be perfect.

```
my $old_file = shift;
my $new_file = shift;
use File::Copy qw(copy);
use File::Basename;

my $directory = dirname( $new_file );

if ($directory eq "/" ) {
     print "Cannot copy file to " .  $new_file .
+" as it does not exist.\n"  ;
    exit (1);
  }

if (-d $directory ) {
    copy( $old_file,$new_file) or die "Copy failed: Directory or file does not exist: $new_file";
    exit ($? >> 8);
  }
  else {
     print "Cannot copy file to " .  $new_file .
+" as it does not exist.\n"  ;
    exit (1);
  }
```

This is the command that runs it

copy_files.pl ${getAbsoluteFileName(print,afp,read)}

Comment: From where is `(job#).print.afp` available? `$1`? Some other var? STDIN?

Comment: After more digging, I found out the main program is Java, the workflow calls for the filename with the getAbsoluteFileName, with the specified parameters (print,afp,read)  So the absolute filename is the job number.print.afp.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments passed to a Perl script are provided in `@ARGV`.

```
use File::Basename qw( basename dirname );
use POSIX          qw( strftime );

my ($old_qfn) = @ARGV;
my $dir_qfn = dirname($old_qfn);
my $old_fn = basename($old_fqn);
my ($job_num) = $old_fn =~ /^(\d+)\.print\.afp\z/
   or die("Invalid input \"$old_qfn\": Doesn't match expected format\n");

my $new_fn = sprintf('ACIF_OUTPUT_%s_%s.afp',
   strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", gmtime(time)),
   $job_num,
);
my $new_qfn = $dir_qfn . '/' . $new_fn;
rename($old_qfn, $new_qfn)
   or die("Can't rename \"$old_qfn\" to \"$new_qfn\": $!\n");
```